# How can I handle nested whens in Joi?

Tags: javascript, joi

I am trying to expect an object like the one below, where data is only allowed if primary is not sent.

```
{
  "action": {
    "primary": "",
    "data": {}
  }
}
```

I have tried this schema:

```
Joi.object({
  action: Joi.object({
    primary: Joi.any(),
    data: Joi.any(),
  })
  .when(Joi.object({
    action: Joi.object({
      primary: Joi.exist()
    })
  }), {
    then: Joi.object({
      primary: Joi
        .string()
        .required(),
      data: Joi.any().forbidden()
    }),
    otherwise: Joi.object({
      primary: Joi.any().forbidden(),
      data: Joi.object()
      .required()
    })
  })
});
```

It is always going into my `otherwise` statement. The other syntax also always fails: `.when('primary', { is: Joi.exist(), then:`

When I try `.when('action.primary', { is: Joi.exist(), then:`, Joi itself errors with `AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Item cannot come after itself: action`

Comment: I think your second idea (`.when('primary'`) is a bit easier to read. Following the error, what happens when you change `'action.primary'` to `'primary'`?

Comment: @JakeWorth either way didn't work. My errors come back saying that data is required, when I mean primary to be required based on the params I sent over.

Comment: I got the same error testing this code; I'm not sure what it means. Proposed answer avoids it by refactoring to a simpler style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could I suggest the following refactor?

```
Joi.object({
  action: Joi.object({
    primary: Joi.string(),
    data: Joi.object().when("primary", {
      is: Joi.exist(),
      then: Joi.forbidden(),
      otherwise: Joi.required()
    })
  })
});
```

It permits both of these objects:

```
{
  action: {
    data: {}
  }
};
```

```
{
  action: {
    primary: "value"
  }
};
```

Note: https://github.com/legraphista/joi-tester is a cool project for validating Joi configuration without setting up an application.

Comment: Accepting this, but do you know how would I be able to make it that when `primary` is there, I also allow `secondary` as another key, on same level? That is partially why I was using the other syntax. I suppose the quickest answer is just to have the when on `secondary` as well :)

Comment: I would add another key `secondary` to the Joi `action` object, that is permitted when `primary` exists. `secondary: Joi.string().when("primary", {` ...